# Can I browse web pages via html by PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Can I browse a web page by PyCharm?

The web page is not in local but say, such as yahoo.com.
I want to take a look without changing the focused window in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer: You used to have one but...

> We used to have built-in browser in IDEA had to abandon it - it turned out that external browser was the better choice since
>
> a) external browser is closer to the one needed for your target (e.g. targeting Chrome, Mobile Safari / Opera, etc)
>
> b) embedded browser does not live well with Swing application (e.g. focus quirks).

It is worth mentioning you can view the raw HTML of a web page by going to: File > Open URL...

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have mentioned my version as well. anywa I did not know about the old ones.
I will use an external web browser. Thanks again!

Comment: There is an off chance that someone wrote a plugin for it (I glanced and didn't see anything) but who knows ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Also!  Thanks for accepting & upvoting...  people rarely do nowadays :(